# Launching android app with no internet connection on device gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, mysql, internet-connection

In these specific conditions my app won't launch:

- No internet connection
- launching on a device

and gives a FileNotFoundException because i don't have any permission (see below for the stack trace). In other circumstances this works. I retrieve my data from a mysql database.
In onCreate method of the Main activity I check for internet connection.

I have these permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am checking internet connection in Main activity:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
         ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
         if(activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable()){
             return true; 
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
```

Error message:

```
11-07 14:15:16.176: E/AndroidRuntime(27318): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-07 14:15:16.176: E/Monkey(27318): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-07 14:15:16.200: E/AndroidRuntime(27318): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-07 14:15:16.200: E/AndroidRuntime(27318): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-07 14:15:16.200: E/AndroidRuntime(27318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 14:15:16.200: E/AndroidRuntime(27318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phi.oudemarkt/com.phi.oudemarkt.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: and you have if(isNetworkAvailable()) { loadData(); } ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add such permission

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE